# Value of custom field in sale.config.settings is not displayed in sales settings view

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I try to add a new configuration field for sales configuration settings by inheriting the standard sales settings view/model using a custom module.

Creating the field in the model works fine and a value entered in the view is also successfully written to the database. 
**However, if I reload the view for sales configuration, the previously stored value is back to 0.00 (while still being ok in the table!).**

Struggling with this for days now, found related posts by research (odoo site and stackoverflow) which all unfortunately did not work for me.

This is the view definition XML file:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!-- SALE CONFIG FORM VIEW Section -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_custom_sale_config_form_inherited">
            <field name="name">sale settings</field>
            <field name="model">sale.config.settings</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_config" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>
                    <xpath expr="//div[@name='Sale Features']/div" position="inside">
                        <div name="threshold_price_mgr_sig">
                            <label for="threshold_price_mgr_sig"/>
                            <field name="threshold_price_mgr_sig" class="oe_inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </xpath>
                </data>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

This is the Python code:

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp

# modify class sale.config.settings to insert a new field
class my_custom_sale_config_settings(osv.osv_memory):
    _name = 'sale.config.settings'
    _inherit = "sale.config.settings"

    _columns = {
        'threshold_price_mgr_sig': fields.float('Threshold Price for Managers Signature', 
            digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price'), 
            default_model='sale.config.settings',
            help="""Threshold price from which the managers signature is required. 
                This is valid for quotations and order confirmations."""),
        }

    _defaults = {
        'threshold_price_mgr_sig': 0.00,
        }

    def get_default_threshold_price_mgr_sig(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
        last_ids = self.pool.get('sale.config.settings').search(cr, uid, [], order='id desc', limit=1)
        result_obj = self.pool.get('sale.config.settings').browse(cr,uid,last_ids[0])
        t_p_m_s = result_obj.threshold_price_mgr_sig

    return {'threshold_price_mgr_sig': t_p_m_s}
```

By debugging I also found, that the function `get_default_threshold_price_mgr_sig` is never executed...

I know that configuration settings fields works different than normal fields - just can't figure out how.

Do you know, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should first add the method for set the value at th e  time of store data in db. otherwise it will returns default value 0.0. 
try using this method:
    def set_default_threshold_price_mgr_sig(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
#ToDo code for store values

Comment: No need to set default value because the float value, default return 0.0

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  @Rutul The vaules entered in the settings form views arrives successfully in the table field in `sale.config.settings` when click the `execute` button - but the form view always displays `0.00` when reloaded. So I think it's not a matter of saving the value but more of loading it and displaying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base configuration wizard for application settings. It provides support for setting default values, assigning groups to employee users, and installing modules. To make such a 'settings' wizard, define a model like::

```
class my_config_wizard(osv.osv_memory):
        _name = 'my.settings'
        _inherit = 'res.config.settings'
        _columns = {
            'default_foo': fields.type(..., default_model='my.model'),
            'group_bar': fields.boolean(..., group='base.group_user', implied_group='my.group'),
            'module_baz': fields.boolean(...),
            'other_field': fields.type(...),
        }
```

The method **execute** provides some support based on a naming convention:

```
*   For a field like 'default_XXX', ``execute`` sets the (global) default value of
the field 'XXX' in the model named by ``default_model`` to the field's value.

*   For a boolean field like 'group_XXX', ``execute`` adds/removes 'implied_group'
to/from the implied groups of 'group', depending on the field's value.
By default 'group' is the group Employee.  Groups are given by their xml id.

*   For a boolean field like 'module_XXX', ``execute`` triggers the immediate
installation of the module named 'XXX' if the field has value ``True``.

*   For the other fields, the method ``execute`` invokes all methods with a name
that starts with 'set_'; such methods can be defined to implement the effect
of those fields.
```

The method `get_default` retrieves values that reflect the current status of the
fields like 'default_XXX', 'group_XXX' and 'module_XXX'.  It also invokes all methods
with a name that starts with 'get_default_'; such methods can be defined to provide
current values for other fields.

> The config page works because when you open the configuration page all the "get_" functions will be called. And when you save it all the "set_" functions are going to run.